# There is any algorithm I can follow to get a Youtube video direct URL?

Tags: algorithm, youtube

I'd like to implement my own library to download videos from Youtube, but I after looking at the questions here at SO I saw that many questions even got a vote and others are outdated.

So to make this question different from the others and more constructive. I'd like to ask if someone could answer, what is the algorithm to discover information about a Youtube video based on its normal URL.

I've read some other people implementation and looks like they build a dictionary (data type) with the information and then passes it to some class that have the capabilities to download the video at the specified format.

Comment: It changes regularly.  It also depends on what device you are using on YouTube.  Different protocols, codecs, and containers are in use depending on many circumstances.  It isn't always simply downloading some file over HTTP anymore.  See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3687981/362536  As for an algorithm, this seems pointless for most applications.  I suggest manually updating your code as conditions change.  Also know that you are likely going to be violating the ToS.

Comment: @Brad I have a question, do you perhaps know if youtube could detect connections that aren't from a browser? Like for example by seeing if javascript or some browser thing is disabled on the client that tries to connect to their server?

Comment: @ShashankGupta, Absolutely.  Now, you can partially work around this by either faking a browser really well or just running a browser like PhantomJS.  Even if you do this, there are behavioral characteristics that can be tracked (such as a video being downloaded an exact number of seconds from page load from the same IP address 24 hours a day).