# Youtube video download error access denied 403

Tags: php, video, download, youtube

i am using this [Athlon1600/youtube-downloader](https://github.com/Athlon1600/youtube-downloader) php script to download youtube videos. Some of the VEVO and other videos are not downloading giving the error 403 Not Authorized. I have tried many scripts but all them failed. But some of the websites are able to generate the links that can download those VEVO videos not sure how. Can any body help?

Here's the link from which the video is downloadable

https://r5---sn-qxoedn7d.c.doc-0-0-sj.sj.googleusercontent.com/videoplayback?itag=22&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&mime=video/mp4&pl=28&dur=234.242&expire=1536600787&c=WEB&ei=c1aWW4oMpIm1B4iZuagL&id=o-AAhuIcHUeeFJYKMi_T5TWB_hzVe9Qd1-1FjH4S6MTAE9&lmt=1532738669204703&ip=107.178.194.20&sparams=dur,ei,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,expire&mt=1536579051&mv=m&ms=au&source=youtube&key=yt6&requiressl=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-qxoedn7d&signature=90BF262E112E3C74C239040D5F90E2CBB4760FF6.D18603AD4220FCF4E4EE71D36CA5D0D926A596BD&downloadvideo=1&title=KatyPerry-Califor-Download-From-ytpak.com&filename=KatyPerry-Califor-Download-From&extension=mp4

And here's the link which is producing error

https://r5---sn-p5qlsndr.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mv=m&dur=234.242&source=youtube&ms=au%2Conr&lmt=1532738669204703&requiressl=yes&ip=205.186.128.210&pl=19&mn=sn-p5qlsndr%2Csn-vgqsknee&pcm2=no&mm=31%2C26&key=yt6&id=o-ADP_WkeslC4LFx1Za7lU4VO9_fMRvl_6T_VExuCpxZ_A&itag=22&mt=1536591076&expire=1536612757&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ei=NYWWW9uRBJSEhwaVzIfYCQ&mime=video%2Fmp4&fvip=5&ratebypass=yes&c=WEB&ipbits=0&signature=FF5B396B5DB649116BCB00D5907EBAF5EB804B45A.2DFC0D69B1860EBE376A4D488747909CD9B674DDD1

Comment: The demos on the GitHub fail so I'd say that API is no longer functional.

Comment: any suggestions where to get the working api?

Comment: I've never used the `youtube-dl` in PHP I've had luck with it command line though. See Mario's answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687859/downloading-youtube-videos-with-php. Also note Brad's answer, and specifically `Finally, keep in mind what you are about to do may be illegal. Check the EULA.`

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using youtube-dl python library. It works great and download almost every video.